# Customizing Web Push Notification (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, push-notification

so I managed to implement a web push notification for Google Chrome using Google Project and Service Worker.

My question is how do I able to customize or decorate the push notification as the message box is plain. For instead, i would like to decorate it with html and css.

```
 self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
 console.log('Push message received', event);
 var title = 'Push message';
 event.waitUntil(
 self.registration.showNotification(title, {
 body: 'Please choose to like or reply      
  icon: 'images/icon.png',
  tag: 'my-tag',
  actions:[
     {action:"like", title: "Like"},
     {action:"reply", title: "⤻ Reply"}]
}));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't add HTML and CSS, at least not yet. What you could do at best is use Emoji's and icons in the title, description and the action buttons but none of the browsers have this feature yet.

Comment: I'm curious if there are any updates on this since it's nearing three years.  I haven't seen anything on google's site but perhaps there is something I'm just missing?

Comment: @dogonaroof Well, 2023 now and it seems that there hasn't been any updates yet.